# 4chan-like inline img expansion (Bootstrap + JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[EDIT]: As of today (11 Sep 2015) I completely rewrote the system, and the question slightly changed its focus: I need to force Bootstrap to shove a fluid column down without resizing the window.

I'm trying to build an Imageboard-like system, and I'm now stuck at the Image Expansion. First, the behavior should be like 4chan: when I click on the Thumbnail, it should expand to the original size, inside the DIV:

1. without breaking the div and "spilling" outside and
2. pushing down the text, so it should not wrap around the div, and
3. when the user clicks the expanded img, it should shrink back to thumbnail.

There is a GIF showing the intended behavior [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHbze.gif).

When I first posted this question I still couldn't emulate the expansion/shrink behavior, now it's finally done. But I have another problem: when I click the image and it expands to its original size, the Bootstrap fluid column where the image sits in (column-md-3) should expand too, so the column right next to it, where the text sits in (column-md-9) should go below the image.

A TEXT representation of the intended behavior:

```
When Image is in "thumbnail" form:

    | SIDEBAR  | column-md-3 (img) | column-md-9 (txt)  |
    |          |                   |                    |

When Image is in "full size" form:

    | SIDEBAR  | column-md-3 (img)                      |
    |          | column-md-9 (txt)                      |
```

For now the current behavior is: when expanded, the image spills out the column div, text is stuck in its place, floating above the img.

I've made a JS Fiddle of whatever I could come with: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fz8n2kh2/). Take heed with the size of rendered HTML iframe from JS Fiddle, it automatically shows the intended behavior (text column goes under the img column) but I want it to happen when the page is in full size, without resizing.

Thank you for your help!

Code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Nothing to see here.
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <a href="http://nerdproject.midiaficcao.com.br/content/080a8f3e26797f14182abbd68ec8a079.png" class="post-image">
                                <img src="http://nerdproject.midiaficcao.com.br/content/thumb/080a8f3e26797f14182abbd68ec8a079.png" data-src="http://nerdproject.midiaficcao.com.br/content/thumb/080a8f3e26797f14182abbd68ec8a079.png" class="image-thumb" />
                            </a>                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            The Text<br/>
                            Should go under<br />
                            The image<br />
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var imageLinks = $('a.post-image');
    imageLinks.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if( $(this).children('img').hasClass("image-thumb")  ) {
            // This is a thumb, switch to original
            fullImg = $(this).children('img').attr('src').replace('thumb/', '');
            $(this).children('img').attr('src', fullImg);
            $(this).children('img').addClass('image-full');
            $(this).children('img').removeClass('image-thumb');
        } else {
            // This is a full image, swith back to thumb
            thumbImg = $(this).children('img').attr('data-src');
            $(this).children('img').attr('src', thumbImg);
            $(this).children('img').addClass('image-thumb');
            $(this).children('img').removeClass('image-full');
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you all who already gave me a hand with the expansion behavior!

PS. If anyone has a suggestion about how to improve the jQuery code, please do so!

CHANGELOG:

6 Sep 2015 - Image would expand, but wouldn't shrink back. Now the behavior is fixed.
11 Sep 2015 - Image expands/shrinks perfectly, breaks column when expanded.

Comment: Can you show an example somewhere? I guess I will be able to do this.

Comment: Put a wrapper node around the image, give this the thumbnail's height and width, also give it relative position. Give the image node absolute positioning. Changing the height and width of the image node will no longer move other page content

Comment: Given that few of us (other than those who already use 4Chan) are likely to visit that site to see what happens, can you show an example elsewhere (or via a link to a YouTube video perhaps) of what you want/expect?

Comment: Thank you all for the interest! I've included a .gif displaying the intended behavior.